# console text padding without background color

Tags: c#, console-application, padding, background-color

I have a loop that writes a string 10 times, each time with a larger padding.
It also sets every other row's background color to dark yellow.

```
int x = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    x = x + 1;
    string str = "word";
    Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(x));
}
```

The problem is that my dark yellow rows are being colored all the way from the start of the rows padding. But I want only the word itself to be dark yellow without the spaces.

Comment: What happens if you pad *before* changing the color?

Comment: Look at `Console.Write(string value)` and not just `Console.WriteLine(string value)`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first write spaces without background color and then write only word with selected background color:

```
int x = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Console.ResetColor();
    if (x > 5)
    {
        Console.Write(new String(' ', x - 5));
    }

    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
    }

    x = x + 1;
    string str = "word";
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just hacked without any testing, but should give an idea of how to make it work:

```
int x = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Console.ResetColor();
    x = x + 1;
    Console.Write("".PadLeft(x));
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;

    string str = "word";
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

The key change is you don't need to write the entire line at a time. You can use `Console.Write()` to write your padding without background colour. Then finish with `Console.WriteLine()` to write the word  + newline.